# How do I get first element rather than using [0] in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to jQuery, apologies if this is a silly question.

When I use it find an element using the id, I know theres always one match and in order to access it I would use the index [0]. Is there a better way of doing this?
For e.g.

```
var gridHeader = $("#grid_GridHeader")[0];
```

Answer (score 124, accepted):

You can use [`.get(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) as well but...you shouldn't need to do that with an element found by ID, that should *always* be unique.  I'm hoping this is just an oversight in the example...if this is the case on your actual page, you'll need to fix it so your IDs are unique, and use a class (or another attribute) instead.

[`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) (like `[0]`) gets the DOM element, if you want a jQuery object use [`.eq(0)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) or [`.first()`](http://api.jquery.com/first/) instead :)

Comment: Except that `$("#id") /* jQuery object */ != $("#id").get(0) /* DOM Object */`

Comment: @BrunoLM - If you want a DOM element, `document.getElementById('id')`, don't create a jQuery object just to throw it away...that's tremendously wasteful, from the selector engine to the object wrapper, it's just overkill for no good reason :)

Comment: Nick I agree, maybe I was being rather silly just using jquery for everthing.

Comment: @NickCraver - Thanks for that. I just replaced a bunch of `document.getElementById('id')` with `$('#id')[0]` but didn't like the `[0]`. Your comment about wastefulness made me think to define `$0 = function(id){return document.getElementById(id);}` and now I like `$0('id')` better. Same number of chars as `$('#id')`, I just wish it could be `$#('id')`

Comment: Wish there was a variant of these methods that returned a falsy value from an empty result set.

Comment: @NickCraver you're (were, 6 years ago) assuming that the jQuery object is thrown away and that it's only used to get a DOM element.

Comment: @BrunoBronosky maybe `return document.querySelector(".myclass")` would work better for your `$0()` shortcut. So you can use it kind of like jQuery, but closer to native and still returning the first element.

Answer (score 39):

`$("#grid_GridHeader:first")` works as well.

Comment: I think this is the best way to handle your issue here.  It reads well, as opposed to .eq(0)

Comment: It *is* the best way for performance reasons too (e.g. when you have a table with 1000 rows, no need to construct a jquery object from all of them)

Answer (score 24):

You can use the first method:

```
$('li').first()
```

http://api.jquery.com/first/

btw I agree with Nick Craver -- use document.getElementById()...

Comment: This returns an empty array if no elements are found. Be careful using in logic statements as `[]` will eval to `true`.

Answer (score 7):

http://api.jquery.com/eq/

```
$("#grid_GridHeader").eq(0)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the first selector.

```
var header = $('.header:first')
```

Comment: Returns an array with single element.

Answer (score 4):

With the assumption that there's only one element:

```
 $("#grid_GridHeader")[0]
 $("#grid_GridHeader").get(0)
 $("#grid_GridHeader").get()
```

...are all equivalent, returning the single underlying element.

From the jQuery source code, you can see that `get(0)`, under the covers, essentially does the same thing as the `[0]` approach:

```
 // Return just the object
 ( num < 0 ? this.slice(num)[ 0 ] : this[ num ] );
```

Comment: Thanks for those everything else works apart from get() which doesn't seem to get the first item.

Comment: Actually I can see from Nick Crave's reply why that won't work

Answer (score -6):

You can try like this:

`yourArray.shift()`