# jquery attr edit only first

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a class="buttonright" onclick="ZZZZ('f')">Post</a>

<a class="buttonright" onclick="sssss('ZZZZ')">Post</a>

$(".buttonright").attr("onclick","new_function_name()");
```

How edit only first?

Comment: `$(".buttonright:eq(0)").click(new_function_name)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get first element rather than using \[0\] in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103810/how-do-i-get-first-element-rather-than-using-0-in-jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use ***jQuery*** [:first Selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) for this purpose like below:-

```js
$("a.buttonright:first").attr("onclick","new_function_name()");

//now click the first link and check that this function is executed or not?
function new_function_name(){
 alert("hello it worked!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="buttonright" onclick="ZZZZ('f')">Post</a>

<a class="buttonright" onclick="sssss('ZZZZ')">Post</a>
```

Reference:- [:first Selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

it's because you're using a class name - classes are general attributes that can apply to multiple elements. In your case, your function targets everything that has the class `buttonright` and then applies the attr value.

Assign id's like so (or similar):

```
<a href="" id="link1" class="buttonright" onclick="ZZZZ('f')">Post</a>
<a href="" id="link2" class="buttonright" onclick="sssss('ZZZZ')">Post</a>
```

then in your js:

```
$('#link1').attr('onclick', 'new_function_name()');
```

however I recommend that you do no inline js, it is bad practice and leads to harder to maintain code.

Comment: You can use `:eq` or `:first` to get first element or nth element

Comment: I cant change html

Comment: @Rajesh you can but that promotes bad practice of wanting something unique on a class

Comment: @user7752471 why can't you change html?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs *bad practice*?? Its normal practice to want to fetch nth element. Try alternate row styling in a table. You will say add different class for all rows but thats just too much effort. You can directly use selectors to get that pattern

Comment: @Rajesh although it's perfectly fine to do that, good practice preaches the use of ids when you want to only change one item. That's the whole point of an id, and adding different ids isn't difficult at all - just a simple foreach loop can add an id to 1000s of elements.

Comment: Lets not go into practices. Also using IDs is good but not always. You will add 1000 IDs and for what? Just say you have a grid with 100 rows and 100 columns. That will create almost 10000 IDs. Yes loop can create it but I don't find it worth

Comment: @Rajesh fair enough - I know there are down to preference :) No I was just using 1000s as an example of how easy it is to add to a large amount of elements - and no, I wasn't suggesting an id on everything - that's ludacris haha my personal preference is add the ids on inputs, parent containers and anything individual, like an img or a link (a tag) :)

Comment: Because use script in not my site

Comment: @user7752471 huh? what's use script? what is the script for? if you are editing the js, you must have some access to the html surely?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs  adding id is really not necessary for this small issue. through class it's possible.check my answer for a better idea.

Comment: @AlivetoDie No I know you can - but in my eyes trying to do unique functions on generic elements seems, well, not logical - otherwise what would be the point in using ids in the first place?