# applying html method of jquery on jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change inner html of an element. If we use this:

```
$('.best-photos-button')[0].innerHTML="Add More Photos";
```

it works fine. But if instead of ".innerHTML" i.e. JavaScript if we use .html() like this :

```
$('.best-photos-button').html("Add More Photos");
```

then it's not working. Why so?
When I am running $('.best-photos-button').innerHTML on console it's giving undefined.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get first element rather than using \[0\] in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103810/how-do-i-get-first-element-rather-than-using-0-in-jquery)

Comment: remove `[0]` from the script `$('.best-photos-button').html("Add More Photos");`

Comment: What makes you think that it **should** be defined? Are you refering to some documentation?

Comment: I put a debugger on js in browser and try to get the value of $('.best-photos-button').innerHTML and output for that should be whatever is in the text in the selected element but it's giving undefined. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 4):

`$('.best-photos-button')` is a jQuery object. When you use `$('.best-photos-button')[0]` it will return the raw DOM element, which does not have a `.html()` method, only `.innerHtml`.

So you either need to use

```
$('.best-photos-button').html("Add More Photos");
```

or use `.innerHtml`

Edit:
Note that if you use `.html()` it will affect all the elements with `best-photos-button` class. So depending on your use case you might need to use a different selector or filter the selection to get the specific object you need.

Comment: Further clarification [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974582/jquery-object-and-dom-element)

Comment: if I am using $('.best-photos-button').html("Add More Photos");  it's not working. The  code is breaking. Also $('.best-photos-button') is added to a single element only.

Comment: Are you calling the method before DOM is loaded? You can use [document "ready"](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to make sure the element is loaded before trying to modify it.

Comment: if that's the case then how this is working : $('.best-photos-button')[0].innerHTML="Add More Photos";

Comment: I'm only guessing, can't say much when there is only 1 line of code.