# select anchor tag within a div element that contains in a variable

Tags: jquery

I am working with a masonry timeline page that has a slider to allow users to jump between different eras.  When a user selects an era, I manage to grab the first masonry using jQuery find method and store it in a variable.

```
let card = $(selectedEraId).find('.cardsImage')[0];
```

card variable is:

```
<div class="cardsImage">
     <a href="#"> text </a>
</div>
```

Now I want to grab the anchor tag.   I tried the following:

```
card.find('a') -> result: find is a not function
card.children() -> result: children is not a function
card.closest('a') -> result: null
```

How do I go about selecting the anchor tag in this scenario?

Comment: Use `.first()` instead of `[0]`.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3103810/how-do-i-get-first-element-rather-than-using-0-in-jquery

Comment: When you index a jQuery collection, it returns the DOM element, not a jQuery object.

Comment: Based on my earlier results, I figured this was the case.

@IhorVyspiansky, I have managed to get the attribute with the anchor tag that I am after


Thank you both for your feedback.